# Read Ebay API xml data with R

Tags: r, xml, list, parsing, get

I am using the ebay API to retrieve some data about current prices using R and GET function to call the API.

```
res <- GET(paste0("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?",
                  "SECURITY-APPNAME=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&",
                   ...
                  "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&",
                  "paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100"))

EbayResult <- content(res, "parsed")
```

The response I get is the below:

```
> EbayResult
{xml_document}
<findItemsByProductResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
[1] <ack>Success</ack>
[2] <version>1.13.0</version>
[3] <timestamp>2019-06-05T07:59:38.940Z</timestamp>
[4] <searchResult count="3">\n  <item>\n    <itemId>264249591631</itemId>\n    <title>ER2315539 Refrigerator Evaporator Motor ...
[5] <paginationOutput>\n  <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>\n  <entriesPerPage>100</entriesPerPage>\n  <totalPages>1</totalPages>\n  ...
[6] <itemSearchURL>http://www.ebay.com/sch/?LH_ItemCondition=1&amp;_ddo=1&amp;_ipg=100&amp;_pgn=1&amp;_productid=1242038032</ ...
```

I would like to extract all the "*itemId*"  in the [4] line, in this example, there are 3 different itemId.
I would like to do this using list or other efficient methods.
Thanks!

Comment: This would help : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_xml_files.htm

Comment: try something like this: `EbayResult %>% XML::xmlParse() %>% XML::xmlToList()`, or maybe `XML::xmlToDataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

@DS_UNI Thanks ! It helped me a lot. From your solution I then just have to loop through the different itemId to get them all:

```
test$searchResult[1]$item$itemId
test$searchResult[2]$item$itemId
...
```